# htaccess rewrite url with extra slash

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code for the htaccess file, and soon I'll have pages where I'd like to create a url like the bottom one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^Index/?$   index.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Gallery/?$   gallery.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Showreel/?$   showreel.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Music/?$   music.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Gallery/Render/?$   contact.php  [NC]
```

If I go to the contact page, it'll display a page, but it's entirely white and only contains the text. I'm guessing it's to do with the images not being linked up properly with the new url, but how would I actually go about fixing this without having to manually edit the locations of each image?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

or change all of your links to absolute URLs. This issue is most likely that your links are all relative, and when you try to request a URL like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/Gallery/Render
```

The relative URI base becomes `/Gallery/` instead of `/` (which is what it is if you access `/contact.php` directly). And when the browser tries to resolve all the relative links on the page, it uses the wrong URI base.

Comment: Thanks, it's not the ideal way I would have done it, but changing it to ../ works fine :)   The problem with the absolute url's is I've not got a proper one yet, and I'd prefer a site which works properly wherever it is :)